# str_replace only replace specific occurence?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, str-replace

I have this SQL command:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO foo (value, value2, value3) 
        VALUES (value1, value2, value3)";
```

And I want to replace the first `)` with `, custom_value)`,
Similarly the second `)` with `, 1234567890)`

The result should be like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO foo (value, value2, value3, custom_value) 
        VALUES (value1, value2, value3, 1234567890)";
```

I tried replacing all occurrences using `str_replace()`.

Is there something with a option to replace only a specific occurrence?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$sql = str_replace('value3', 'value3, %s', $sql);
$sql = sprintf($sql, 'custom_value', '1234567890');
```

Test on my local setup:

```
$sql = '(value, value2, value3) (value1, value2, value3)';
$sql = str_replace('value3', 'value3, %s', $sql);
$sql = sprintf($sql, 'custom_value', '1234567890');

// produces (value, value2, value3, custom_value) (value1, value2, value3, 1234567890)
echo $sql;
```

Here is a reusable function:

```
function replace_occurence($search, $replace, $subject) {
        $subject = str_replace($search, '%s', $subject);
        array_unshift($replace, $subject);
        return call_user_func_array('sprintf', $replace);
}
$sql = '(value, value2, value3) (value1, value2, value3)';
$sql = replace_occurence(')', array(', custom_value)', ', 123456790)'), $sql);
```

Comment: @Kaii completely missed the question :S, will be deleting this soon. Thanks

Comment: @Kaii I tested locally and it works producing `(value, value2, value3, custom_value) (value1, value2, value3, 1234567890)` so not quite sure what you mean by "sprintf() will silently fail", did you test my code or I'm missing something here?

Comment: @andreas well your are right in this point, i responded too fast. But what i initally said is still valid: This is just an example and *it is very **unlikely** that `value3` is the value for the field `value3` in production code*. The OP requested to replace *the parenthesis* and that is really what you should do. Code that only works on a specific example is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 1):

For the example you gave.. you can you use this regex:

```
#(\).+?\(.+)(\))#
```

In PHP code, it looks like this:

```
$sql = preg_replace("#(\).+?\(.+)(\))#", 
                    ", custom_value\1, 1234567890\2", 
                    $sql, -1, $count);
```

it will search for a closed parenthesis followed by an open parenthesis, and after that will look for the latest closed parenthesis

Example:
http://xrg.es/#b1uu3f

Comment: only works on the specific example .. actual SQL code would look like this: `INSERT INTO foo (value, value2, value3) VALUES (value1, value2, value3)`, which the regex fails to replace correctly.

Comment: Simple fix for the issue you suggested.. now the code should work

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing in the basic function set of PHP. But you can implement it using [`substr_replace()`](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.substr-replace.php).

```
$sql = "foo (bar, baz, blub) bar (boo, far, faz)";

// only replace first occurance
$firstpos = strpos($sql, ')');
$sql = substr_replace($sql, ', custom_value)', $firstpos, 1);

// only replace second occurance
$secondpos = strpos( $sql, ')', strpos( $sql, ')' ) + 1);
$sql = substr_replace( $sql, ', 123456)', $secondpos, 1);

echo $sql, PHP_EOL;
```

Results:

```
foo (bar, baz, blub, custom_value) bar (boo, far, faz, 123456)
```

**Rewritten as a reusable function:**

```
function str_replace_occurance($search, $replace, $subject, $occurance) {
   $pos = NULL;
   for ($i = 1; $i <= $occurance; $i++) {
       $pos = strpos($subject, $search, ($pos===NULL) ? 0 : $pos+1);
   }
   return substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($search));
}

$sql = str_replace_occurance(')', ', custom_value)', $sql, 1);
$sql = str_replace_occurance(')', ', 1234567890)', $sql, 2);
echo $sql, PHP_EOL;
```

Edit: reordered parameters to have the same order and name as the original `str_replace`

Answer (score -1):

If you have php > 5.0 you can use `count` in `str_replace` to set how many replacements you need.

Comment: the `count` parameter is actually a variable reference where `str_replace()` will return the count of replaced occurances. It is *not* a limit or offset parameter.

Answer (score -1):

If using only str_replace then str_replace with limit for 1st and again replace it for second one...

http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: there is no limit parameter for `str_replace()`. Also if there was one, the second call would still replace the first occurance.